# Copy attributes by intersection (point on line) PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis

I have a PostGIS database, with 2 layers: a point and a line. I import these layers into QGIS (set snap to 10 pixels), draw a line, then I draw a point on that line. Then i select the point and verify if the point geometry intersect line geometry and it is false.

The question is why? Below is the piece of code that I'm using:

```
for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
  if lyr.name() == 'line':
    l_layer = lyr
  elif lyr.name() == 'point':
    p_layer = lyr
  print 'ok'

featSelected = p_layer.selectedFeatures()

for l in l_layer.getFeatures():
  if featSelected[0].geometry().intersects(l.geometry()):
    print 'ok'

for line in l_layer.getFeatures():
  if featSelected[0].geometry().intersects(line.geometry()):
     value = line["guidCON"]
     idSelected = featSelected[0].id()
     fieldIndex = p_layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex("guidCON")
     p_layer.changeAttributeValue(idSelected,fieldIndex,value.lstrip())
```

Comment: When you drew the line, did you save the layer?

Comment: Yes, i drew the line, save and after that i made a point on it.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

It is a problem related to geometry accuracy. A punt stored has an accuracy in its coordinates with a large decimal number, but a vector line is the union between 2 points. When qgis calculates the intersection in the line i gues there is always a very small distance between point and line due to the diferent accuracy.

To solve this, first i must to create a new node into the line, then you are able to insert, in the new node, a feature point. In the image above a spatial query "intersects" 3 red points in a line, only nodes line intersects with points, the green dots .
In the following image is shown a JTS TestBuilder capture. A line and a point intersects, in predicates we see a True in Intersects.

[image]